# Jenkins: Finding root pom.xml in OSX

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

Ive been searhcing and I cannot find the path to the pom.xml for ROOT POM in Jenkins Project on my macbook

on my comp, the path is here: `/eclipse/.../workspace/test/pom.xml`
but when I insert that into the ROOT POM space, the error shows:
ERROR: NO SUCH FILE

```
/eclipse/.../workspace/test/pom.xml
```

What do I put to the path to get to my pom? THanks!

Comment: I think we are a little underinformed here. Try explaining yourself in more details. Is jenkins on same machine? How is the jenkins job configured to access the source? through some code repository?

Comment: Jenkins is on the same machine. In windows, I just do something like "C:\directory\...\pom.xml" but I cannot find the pom path using osx! :(

Comment: post more information: which host is running jenkins, where is the project placed, how is jenkins configured to run the job

Answer (score -1):

Jenkins is on the same machine, and Project is also locally under users on My machine,

Job is configured as "maven project" in jenkin, every thing is on My System